# ASP.NET WebSecurity object shared between projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First of all, I'm not familiar with Web development so I might be missing something basic here. Do excuse me if that's really the case.

I'm currently working on a web application (not created by me), which is based on another web app.
Both applications share similar user log in code, but user account info are stored in different databases.

However, after logging in to 1 of the app, the WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated flag is also true on the other app (detected as logged on). Is this behaviour expected?

In case this information is of any use..

- 1 of the app uses *ASP.NET development server* while the other uses *ISS express*.

Comment: I guess your web.config has same settings for both application, validationkey and decryptionkey etc, read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Esa Thanks! It does seem to be related to what you mentioned. Both projects did not define machinekey in Web.config. So I went ahead and put in a different manually generated key. But now they seem to be "hijacking" each other. I'm getting "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted..." when logging in to both web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer to my initial question.
That has been answered by @Esa in the comment above --> Setting machine key to Web.Config.

The following is an answer to the problem I mentioned in the comment.
(Should I have posted this in comment instead?)

Both applications were overwriting the same __RequestVerificationToken cookie, which caused error "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted..." when navigating.

This is because both applications were at the same path of "localhost:xxxxx" and hence detected as the same site. The error can be avoided by changing the virtual path of either application.

- For VS, Project properties -> Web (tab) -> Virtual path